# Scaling a fill pattern in raphael.js

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, scale, raphael, fill

```
paper=Raphael('previewBody',480,480);
paper.path({"stroke-width":1},'M0,0 L480,240 L480,480 L240,480 z')
  .attr('fill','url(bg.png)'))
  .scale(.5,.5,0,0);
```

My problem is the fill is not scaled with the svg canvas, so proportionally, it ends up as twice the size it was before the scale of the path.
Is there any easy way to scale the fill pattern along with the rest of the svg?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is note possible to do it by using only the functions of the raphael library.

When you apply the scale function on a raphael's object, it creates a new svg node, with the coordinates scaled, but unfortunately, it doesn't modify the fill properties

Anyway, when you add the attribute "fill" with an url, the library create a pattern.
If it is the first "fill" attribute that you use, this pattern is called `raphael-pattern-0` the next one is called `raphael-pattern-1`, etc...)

Knowing this, it is then possible to change the attribute of the pattern, according to the [SVG specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/pservers.html#Patterns)

You can get the attributes of the pattern with `document.getElementById("raphael-pattern-0")` and change its properties with the `setAttribute`
For example (depending on what you really want to do), it could be something like:

```
var pat = document.getElementById("raphael-pattern-0");
pat.setAttribute("height", pat.getAttribute("height")*0.5);
pat.setAttribute("width", pat.getAttribute("width")*0.5);
```

You can also modify the `x`, `y`, `patternUnits` and `patternContentUnits` properties.

Hope it will answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why but my version of Raphael library (I use newest) doesn't put ID as @ThibThib described. It's probably because we have 2013 now:)

I will post my solution as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Raphael Test</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/raphael.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="raphael"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var raphael, path, pattern;

                raphael = Raphael(document.getElementById('raphael'), 500, 500);

                path = raphael.circle(200, 200, 180);
                path.attr('stroke', '#000000');
                path.attr('stroke-width', 3);
                path.attr('stroke-opacity', 1);
                path.attr('fill', 'url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_M4WdA9j-b-g/TLMF9JJJwcI/AAAAAAAAAV4/p0Y_Wo3S3sQ/s1600/Landscape1.jpg)');
                pattern = $(path.node).attr('fill');
                if(pattern) {
                    pattern = pattern.replace('url(', '').replace(')', '');
                    pattern = $(pattern);
                }

                // Shape element documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846327(v=vs.85).aspx#shape_element
                // Fill element documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb229596(v=vs.85).aspx

                setTimeout(function() {
                    if(Raphael.vml) { // SVG not supported (IE7 & IE8) and it doesn't work :/

                        var html = $(path.node).html();
                        html = html.replace(/rvml:/g, ''); // remove prefix
                        html = html.replace(/ = /g, '=');
                        html = html.substr(html.indexOf('/>') + 2); // remove xml element

                        var src = '';
                        $(html).each(function() {
                            if($(this).prop("tagName") == 'FILL') {
                                src = $(this).attr('src');
                            }
                        });

                        if(src != '') {
                            var html = $(path.node).html();
                            html = html.replace(src, src + '" size="50,50');
                            $(path.node).html(html);
                            path.attr('stroke', '#000000');
                            path.attr('stroke-width', 3);
                            path.attr('stroke-opacity', 1);
                        }
                    }
                    else { // SVG supported and it prints correct URL
                        $(pattern)[0].setAttribute('width', 50);
                        $(pattern)[0].setAttribute('height', 50);
                        $(pattern).find('image')[0].setAttribute('width', 50);
                        $(pattern).find('image')[0].setAttribute('height', 50);
                        $(pattern).find('image')[0].setAttribute('preserveAspectRatio', 'defer none meet');
                    }
                }, 1000);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice few things:

- accessing VML fill image is described here: [How to access Raphael fill image in VML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371038/how-to-access-raphael-fill-image-in-vml/14371773#14371773)
- after changing size of image I had to reset stroke for VML version
- for some reason jQuery `.attr` didn't work for me, so I used `setAttribute` (Chrome)
- I set `preserveAspectRatio` to achieve same effect as in VML. You can disable it if you want to see differences ([see documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute))
- `setTimeout` is used to wait for image to be loaded, as SVG was setting params after image was loaded, and it was overwriting my size change

You can of course play with different settings as well:

[VML Fill element documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb229596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[SVG Patterns](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#Patterns)

[SVG Image element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElement)